# Google apps script html printing code instead of running

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have the following stored in a google script html file named 'temp':

```
<body>

    <table>
      <? var feedback = getDatabaseFeedback();
          for (var i=0; i < feedback.length; i++){ ?>
        <tr>
        <? for (var j=0; j < feedback[i].length; j++) { ?>
          <td> <?= feedback[i][j] ?> </td>
        <? } ?>
        </tr>
      <? } ?>
    </table>

</body>
```

This is being served from a google script file:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('temp');
}
```

But instead of running the code within the `"<? ?>"` tags, it is actually printing the code to the screen in the browser. Am I doing something wrong here ? please advise ..

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning createHtmlOutputFromFile in the doGet method, when using templates the following should be used:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('temp').evaluate();
}
```